# What is the cleanest way to disable postback controls until the page has fully loaded?

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have a website that has some intense graphics, and people with slow connections might require download time.  While their browser is downloading, they have form options. And a lot of times they will fill the form out and hit submit.

This causes an event validation issue, because the page wasn't fully loaded.  I can think of a lot of ways off the top of my head to fix this. I could go back and disable every single control, and then write javascript to enable these controls clientside when the page is loaded.

I also looked into blockui, but it will block the whole page or just a div. I am looking for something I can stick in my masterpage and forget about it.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like the correct approach would be to load in your intense graphics after-the-fact, so that users can still submit forms as soon as the critical DOM elements are rendered. (I'm assuming it's not vitally important that all the images be loaded before the form gets submitted?)

You could do this fairly easily by causing your images to be loaded as CSS-based backgrounds on `div` and `body` elements, based on a specific class, like this:

```
body.loaded {background: black url("http://us.battle.net/sc2/static/images/layout/body-bg-baked.jpg") center top no-repeat;}
```

Then have the following code to add that class after the page loads:

```
$(window).load(function() {$('body').addClass('loaded');});
```

It shouldn't produce any significant slow-down in the loading of the images, but it will allow all your page's DOM elements and javascript to run while those images are downloading if necessary.

([jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/Umdnb/4/))

Comment: It's my entire site theme, which is about 2mb in graphics. Video gaming site, so it's got high end graphics.  I'd like them to load asap.  I am looking for some JS that can disable all buttons using a jquery selector, and then re-enable them when dom is done

Comment: @bladefist: IMO, Even a video gaming site ought to be functional while users are waiting for 2mb of graphics to download. What's causing the validation issue, exactly? It seems like you ought to be able to structure your page in a way that things behave properly even though the images haven't loaded up.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't explain the answer myself. But I think this has the gist of what you need to do. 
http://www.telerik.com/community/forums/aspnet/ajax/disable-or-gray-out-page-when-displaying-loading-panel.aspx